# Not able to transfer ETH via MetaMask using web3.js

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets

So I try to transfer the funds using below code its working in metamask extension its shows SEND Ether

```
amountToSent = "0.002"
web3.eth.sendTransaction(
    {from: ethereum.selectedAddress,to: receverAddress, value: web3.utils.toWei(amountToSent, "ether")},
    function(err, transactionHash) {
      if (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err);
            //$('#status').html('Payment failed');
        } else {
            console.log("Payment was successful... data returned is: ", transactionHash);
            
       }
    }
);
```

but I want to transfer funds using abi contacts I tried below code and when metamask extension open it shows TRANSFER
transfer was success but wont received in receiver account

```
var abi = [...]

var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
var amountToSent = "0.002"
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, receverAddress, , { from: ethereum.selectedAddress });

contract.methods.transfer(address,web3.utils.toWei(amountToSent, "ether") )
   .send().then(receipt=> {console.log(receipt)});
```

the amount which show in metamask in too big
& I think I want to transfer ether
I'm attaching the image of that

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To call a contract function and send ether in the same transaction you have to use the `value` parameter from `send()`.

```
var abi = [...]

var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
var amountToSent = "0.002"
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, receverAddress, , { from: ethereum.selectedAddress });

contract.methods.transfer(address, param2)
   .send({
      from: ethereum.selectedAddress,
      value: web3.utils.toWei(amountToSent, "ether"),
   }).then(receipt=> {console.log(receipt)});
```